# Add indirect dependiencies to output

Tags: c#, .net, build, .net-assembly

I have an issue with and indirect assembly.

I have an **external dll** wich is reference from  **project B**.  **Project B** is referenced from  **project A** which is the project I build and deploy. When I build the  **external dll** don't get included in the build of  **project A**.

I don't really want to add another reference to the  **external dll** in  **project A**, isn't there a way that Visual studio can include the  **external dll** in my build automatically?

Thanks,
Jesper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, in order to distinguish between a 32 bit and a 64 bit version i had renamed my external dll reflecting if it was the 32 or 64 bit version. And I guess that the assembly name and the filename of the assembly must match and this was not the case i my application.

When the names matched Visual Studio copied the files nice and easy :)